# How to prevent new lines appearing after inserting Paragraphs with OpenXML?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to insert text into `Bookmarks` in an OpenXML .docx file, but it's inserting a new line after each `Paragraph`. How can I prevent this?

e.g.:
[image]

I add the text to the document by finding the `Bookmarks` with the following:

```
var bmk= body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().FirstOrDefault(xx => xx.Name == "myBMK");
var parent = bmk.Parent;

parent.InsertBeforeSelf(GetText("DaveCompany"));
```

where `GetText` is defined as:

```
public static Paragraph GetText(string cellText)
{
    var run = new Run(new Text(cellText));

    return new Paragraph(run);
}
```

I've tried stripping the text out of a `Paragraph`, e.g.

```
    parent.InsertBeforeSelf(new Run(new Text("DaveCompany")));
```

but that produced an invalid document.

How can I prevent the new line from being inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was adding the extra line because the Bookmark was in its own paragraph. When I added the new paragraph with

```
parent.InsertBeforeSelf(GetText("DaveCompany"));
```

The container table cell had 2 paragraphs in it, and the document displayed this as it effectively *should* have.

The solution is to remove the bookmark's parent paragraph after I have inserted the text, e.g.

```
var bmk= body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().FirstOrDefault(xx => xx.Name == "myBMK");
var parent = bmk.Parent;

parent.InsertBeforeSelf(GetText("DaveCompany"));
parent.Remove();
```